# Looking for a CLI application that allows me to connect to server over SSH quickly

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line-interface

I'm looking for a CLI opensource application (Debian, Ubuntu) that allows me to connect quickly to a server using SSH. When I have a new server I just once configure the servers just once. After this, I just invoke the application and select the server from a listing. For example:

```
1. foo@whatever-server-i-have
2. bar@more-servers.nl
3. myuser@dev-server-whatever
```

This would save me the trouble of typing the SSH command and specify the correct key etc. I thought that funtoo keychain (https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) was the thing I am was looking for but it seems more like a tool that manages the ssh key passwords. (Would also be nice to have).

Does anybody know an application that does what I just described or something that looks like it?

Comment: "This would save me the trouble of typing the SSH command and specify the correct key etc." In ssh configuration file you can define both host aliases and keys to use, which means you can have commands as short as `ssh a`, what more do you need? Also by default you have autocompletion normally (taking all names in ssh config) so you shouldn't even have to write full names most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, CLI means for me, it must be on the command line - no graphical interface wanted. The best linux ssh client still is `ssh`.
You can use `.ssh/config` to define custom host definitions, which include username, ip, port, path to keyfile:

```
Host a
    Hostname 10.1.2.3
    Port     3333
    User     root
    IdentityFile /path/to/keyfile
```

that way, you can just execute `ssh a`, and you are connected. Those host definitions support all [ssh_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) options. Modern linux systems even support bash completion on the Alias Name defined in `.ssh/config` - from my point of view, you cannot get more comfort on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, using /.ssh/config will do for now!